# Como "escapar" o @ no Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, razor

Estou tentando deixar @ como string. Aqui está o código:

```
hint: {
mentions: ['Pedro', 'Tiago', 'João', 'Maria'],
match: /\B@(\w*)$/, // Problema com @
search: function (keyword, callback) {
    callback($.grep(this.mentions, function (item) {
        return item.indexOf(keyword) == 0;
    }));
},
content: function (item) {
    return '@' + item;  // Problema com @
    }    
},
```

As linhas marcadas enfrentam o problema de @.

O problema é @, ele entende como sintaxe de modelo. Como deixar ele como string ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ironicamente (ou não) quem faz o escape do **`@`** é o próprio **`@`**.

Usar `@@` deve funcionar.